# Python Speech Recognition not working when the file is converted to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, speech-recognition

I created a Voice Assistant using speech recognition and GTTS modules in Python. The code works perfectly fine when run from script. But when I converted it using **pyinstaller --onefile Speak.py**(The name of the file) it stopped working. It is using my microphone but its not responding to anything. Suppose if I say hey google which is the wake up keyword it simply doesnt respond. I tried after a while but of no use. Can anyone please help me???

Code:

```
"from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import playsound
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

keeprunning = True

WAKING = "HEY GOOGLE"
def chec(cond, tex):
    if cond in tex:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def speak(text):
    speaker = gTTS(text = text, lang = "en")
    speaker.save("Voice.mp3")
    playsound.playsound("voice.mp3")
    os.remove("Voice.mp3")
def cleanify(text, wtremove, wtremove2=""):
    try:
        text = text.replace(wtremove)
    except:
        if not wtremove2 == "":
            text = text.replace(wtremove2, "")
    return text

#Main controlling part here(Oof!)
def Control(comnd):
    if chec("SEARCH", comnd) or chec("GOOGLE", comnd):
        comnd = cleanify(comnd, "SEARCH", "GOOGLE")
        webbrowser.open(f"https://google.com/search?q={comnd.lower()}")

    elif chec("WHO ARE YOU", comnd):
        speak("I am your virtual assistant, google")
        keepcontrol()

    elif chec("TIME", comnd):
        t = datetime.now()
        t = time.strptime(t.strftime("%H:%S"), "%H:%M")
        tt = time.strftime( "%I:%M %p", t )
        speak(f"The current time is {tt}")
    elif chec("NOTE", comnd) or chec("REMEMBER", comnd) or chec("JOT", comnd):
        try:
            text = comnd.replace("NOTE")
        except:
            try:
                text = text.replace("REMEMBER")
            except:
                text = text.replace("JOT")
        try:
            with open("This_File_Name_Is_Very_Big_Because_I_dont_Want_to_overwrite_anyother_files_so_forgive_me_plz.txt", "rt") as file:
                previous = file.read()
        except:
            with open("This_File_Name_Is_Very_Big_Because_I_dont_want_to_overwrite_any_other_files_so_forgive_me_plz.txt", "wt") as file:
                ttw = f"""
                    •{text.lower()}
                """
                file.write(previous + ttw)
                previous = ""

        with open("Notes.txt", "wt") as file:
            ttw = previous + "  •" + text

            file.write(ttw)
        speak("Got it! I noted it down")

    elif chec("OPEN", comnd):
        web = cleanify(comnd, "OPEN")
        bruh = cleanify(web, ".com")
        speak(f"Opening {bruh}")
        print(comnd)
        web = cleanify(comnd, "OPEN")
        if web == "":
            web = listen()
        else:
            if "https://" in web:
                webbrowser.open(web.lower())
            else:
                web = "https://" + web
                webbrowser.open(web.lower())
        keepcontrol()
        
#Main controlling part ends

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        listen = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(listen)
            return text.upper()
        except Exception as e:
            if not e == "":
                return ""
                keepcontrol()
            else:
                speak("Sorry we couldnt catch that, please try again")
                keepcontrol()

def keepcontrol():
    while keeprunning:
        text = listen()
        if not text == None:
            if text.count(WAKING) == 1:
                speak("I am listening..")
                text = listen()
                if not text == None and not text == "":
                    Control(text)
                else:
                    speak("Sorry i did not get that. Try again in a few seconds")
                    keepcontrol()
            elif chec("QUIT", text):
                exit()
            elif chec("", text):
                keepcontrol()
            else:
                speak("Sorry we didnt get that right. Please try again.")
                        
                
        
speak("I am booting up...")
keepcontrol()
"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have converted it into exe,I think you have forgot to put files that you have used to build the assistant in the folder.
When your exe get converted, just simply copy those files(the files you have used) in the same folder in which you have kept your exe.
Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I havent used any external files. Its a file with no external dependencies except the modules.

Comment: @ÌÆMÁẞÍËÑ But in your code there is a file .

Comment: There are only two files in my code. Voice.mp3 and This_File_Name_Is_Very_Big_Because_I_dont_Want_to_overwrite_anyother_files_so_forgive_me_plz.txt , and voice.mp3 is created and deleted as soon as its work is finished and the file with the big name is the Notes file. It doesnt need to be moved the code itself creates it so i dont think theres a problem with the files theres a problem with the recognition part so im just finding a solution to it so the code works properly without any errors at all.